# ReactJS: componentWillReceiveProps is called on state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to solve a scenario, where parent would include a Module and when a button is clicked inside parent, Module will appear.

Now, there will be a close button in Module, clicking on which will hide the Module. Next time parent button is clicked, Module should appear again, and so on.

Code so far:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return{
      showModule: false
    };
  },
  render(){
    return(
        <div className="parent" onClick={this._showModule}>
          Click me to show module
          <Module show={this.state.showModule}/>
        </div>
    );
  },
  _showModule(){
    this.setState({
      showModule: true
    });
  }
});

var Module = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return{
      show: this.props.show
    };
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps is called');
    this.setState({
      show: nextProps.show
    });
  },
  render(){
    return(
      (this.state.show?
        <div className="module" onClick={this._hide}>
          Click me and I will disappear myself
        </div> : null
      )
    );
  },
  _hide(){
    this.setState({
      show: false
    });  
  }
});
```

The problem here is, whenever I call the hide function in Module (which hides itself by changing state.show to false), **componentWillReceiveProps** gets called.

Shouldn't it get called only when Parent is passing new props? How and why would state change in child Module invoke componentWillReceiveProps?

JsBin http://jsbin.com/cunuci/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on the "Click me and I will disappear myself" you actually click on the Parent and called Parent._showModule handler.
Change

```
<div className="parent" onClick={this._showModule}>
  Click me to show module
  <Module show={this.state.showModule}/>
</div>
```

to

```
<div className="parent">
   <p onClick={this._showModule}>Click me to show module</p>
   <Module show={this.state.showModule}/>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/naloxafile/1/edit?js,console,output